# Convert my drive from MBR to GPT

Tags: partitioning, mbr, gpt

I installed windows 10 in MBR partitioned table.

Due to mistake, I delete c:/ drive data and want to install fresh windows but it requires GPT partition table whereas my D & E drive were in MBR partition previously.

I want to install fresh windows in my c:/ drive and also convert my drive to GPT without losing any data from D:/ & E:/ drive.

Is this any method? Please help me

Comment: I am finding this difficult to follow. Maybe a list showing what was part of what would help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I cannot follow this well either. But if you have data on a drive MBR which you wish to be GPT, then back up your data on the MBR drive as you will need to reformat it (lose all) to get to GPT.

Comment: [mbr2gpt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when upgrading from Windows 10 to 11 (and there were many paid solutions/apps online with few simple solutions I could find). However, it's pretty easy to do it yourself with a single command. Convert MBR to GPT (even on the partition containing the active Windows 10 OS) with the admin command:

```
mbr2gpt /convert /disk:# /allowFullOS
```

where `#` is the disk index (usually `0` for `C:`) obtained from the disk manager. You can run this command on multiple drives without losing any data.